# Get content inside rendered embed tag with src

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to know how to query the content of an embed tag using src.
I've an embed tag where I use a custom page as src.

[image]

I need to access to the rendered content using jquery, but I just get nothing.

[image]

Any idea or help will be appreciated!

TIA!
Milton

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure, whether embed tag supports html file or not. but if source is any SVG document. Here is how you can achieve it.

add some selector to your embed tag and then access by using `getSVGDocument()`

HTML

```
<embed id="myembed" src="some src" width="100%" height="100%">
```

JS

```
$('#myembed').getSVGDocument()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Ashish! Thanks for your answer, but did you tried it before ?

Comment: yes I did, it worked fine in chrome. What is your browser version

Comment: 36.0.1985.125 m. Are you using something in src ?

Comment: Ashish, please refer to an external html page in src. If you can get the content (like a div) from inside the src page rendered, then you have the answer :)

Comment: I missed your code, embedding other html in embed tag. I tried with embedding image and worked fine with getSVGDocment. I tried multiple ways to figure out solution for you, but none worked. Is there any specific need why you can use iframe.

Comment: Yes, I'm using iframes now, but wanted to start using embed. Thanks for your help Ashish!